# "Freestyle" lines not complete, missing or inexplicable

Tags: freestyle

See title. I marked the inexplicable lines red and the missing ones green, how I would like it to be. I use cycles, does that matter anyway? What settings do I have to use or is there a good comprehensible introduction?

The ornament is one (applied boolean unison) object.

[image]